# Socket program freezes on load

Tags: vb.net

The program freezes on load. At first it was working as it was supposed to, but after I cleaned and built the solution, it only freezes on load. The weird part is that it only freezes and it does not show the exception message for the catch.

here is the class file I used

```
Imports System.Net ' for IPAddress
Imports System.Net.Sockets 'for TcpListener

Public Class clientSocket
Dim aString As String
Dim port As Integer 'this is the port number
Dim localAddr As IPAddress ' this is the IP address
Dim client As TcpClient ' This is for the TCP/IP Protocol
Dim clientListener As TcpListener

Public Function startSocket() As String
    Try
        'define the two values for your Server
        port = 1234
        localAddr = IPAddress.Loopback 'loopbak = 127.0.0.1 = myself
        clientListener = New TcpListener(localAddr, 4321)
        client = New TcpClient(localAddr.ToString, port)
        Return "Connected to the server"
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return ex.Message
    End Try
End Function

Public Function receive() As String
    Try
        clientListener.Start()
        Dim mySocket As Socket
        mySocket = clientListener.AcceptSocket()
        Dim recieveBuff(225) As Byte
        mySocket.Receive(recieveBuff, recieveBuff.Length, SocketFlags.None)
        Dim str As String = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(recieveBuff, 0, recieveBuff.Length).Trim(Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(0))
        Return str
        mySocket.Receive(recieveBuff, recieveBuff.Length, SocketFlags.None)
        str = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(recieveBuff, 0, recieveBuff.Length).Trim(Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(0))
        clientListener.Stop()
    Catch exp As Exception
        Return "Exception: " + exp.Message
    End Try
End Function
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mySocket = clientListener.AcceptSocket()
```

These lines block further action untill a socket has been acepted, it will block your code until a socket has been accepted. Use thread to prevent blocking

Answer (score 0):

Or use [BeginAcceptSocket](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.beginacceptsocket.aspx), but you'll have to move your receive code to the callback.